# PHP - Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem regarding my correct script for query..

I created a form in page1.php where the user have to input the fname, mname, and lname.

page1.php

```
<form action = "page2.php" method="post" target="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">

First Name:<input type="text" name="fname"/>
Middle Name:<input type="text" name="mname"/>
Last Name:<input class = "type="text" name="lname"/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="NEXT" />              
</form>
```

The entries are sent to page2.php to be inserted into the database. After successful process. I placed a condition after a successful insertion of the values, it automatically goes to page3.php.

page2.php

```
<?php

    include('config.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $fname = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['fname']));
        $lname = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['lname']));
        $mname = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['mname']));



        $submit=$_POST['submit'];

        if(empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($mname))
        {
            echo '<b>Please fill out the form completely.</b>';
        }

        else
        {
            $dup = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                FROM 
                                tbl 
                                WHERE 
                                fname = '$fname' 
                                AND 
                                lname = '$lname'
                                AND
                                mname = '$mname'
                                ");

            if(mysql_num_rows($dup) >0)
            {
                echo "<br/>";
                echo '<b>Already Registered.</b>';
                echo "<br/>";
            }

            else 
            {   
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl(fname,lname,mname) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$mname')");
                if($sql)
                {
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "You have successfully added your new name!";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    header("Location: page3.php?fname= $fname&mname= $mname &lname= $lname");   
                }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Error Registration";
                        header("Location: index.php");
                    }
            }
            }

            }

            ?>
```

The values will also be carried over by the:

```
header("Location: page3.php?fname= $fname&mname= $mname &lname= $lname");
```

which is placed right after the:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl(fname,lname,mname)VALUES('$fname','$lname','$mname')");
```

Then goes to next page.

In page3.php, in order to verify that I still have the values I used:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_GET,true) . '</pre>';
```

And I still have them.

Now, in page3.php I want to call the auto_incremented ID that was created after the successful insertion of the values from page2.php.

```
<?php

    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_GET,true) . '</pre>';     

    include('config.php');

    $fname = $_GET['fname'];
    $mname = $_GET['mname'];
    $lname = $_GET['lname'];

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fname = '$fname' AND mname = '$mname' AND lname = '$lname'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    echo $row['id'];
    }
?>
```

Now, the problem is that their no results coming out from my query. When I try this is script:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl");
```

I have results showing up.

What I want to do is this, I want the conditions to be fulfilled altogether namely the fname, mname, lname. The 3 fields must be satisfied so that I can get the specified ID from the table which has those fields specifically. Its like you have the query your fullname and get the ID for you. You should insert all 3 fields in order to get the exact ID for that given name.

My problem probably lies here:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fname = '$fname' AND mname = '$mname' AND lname = '$lname'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    echo $row['id'];
    }
```

It's like you to have John Rogers Smith then find out your ID from the database.

Can you help me? I dont understand why it's not working.

Tnx guys in advance.

Comment: There is a syntax error here: `Last Name:<input class = "type="text" name="lname"/>`

Comment: a word of advice, use the mysqli extension instead of the mysql extension. The mysql extension is depricated in the lastest version 5.5.x of PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: you might also have wrong values in url parameters.so try printing only $_GET variables and check whether you have correct values

Comment: arkascha the class = will just be ignored because its just for css purpose only. tnx anyways

Comment: Lex, I know the mysql extension is depreciated but for the mean time im practicing on the old ones. I will be using the mysqli extension sooner or later tnx

Comment: kris, I was able to print the variables which has those values. I was able to confirm it using the print_r($_GET, true)

Answer (score 0):

Please check every stap you do, because the form already has an error

```
Last Name:<input class = "type="text" name="lname"/>
```

needs to be

```
Last Name:<input class="" type="text" name="lname"/>
```

and the way you do the querys is not secure, its easy to do sql injection.

Also i would suggest you to use [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/sprintf), example:

```
$s_query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `x` WHERE `x`.`x_name` = '%s'", $x_name);
```

And you should go for [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) instead of mysql.

Next time always print out every stap, use [print_r()](https://www.php.net/print_r) to print arrays like $_GET and $_POST

Answer (score 0):

```
may i ask to all it may work without give error or warning

 echo "Error Registration";
 header("Location: index.php");
```